# Check isKindOfClass to Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary objects. In for loop i want to check whether each object in the array isKindOfClass dictionary or not.

```
var xxxStatus = jsonResponse as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
var applications = xxxStatus["status"] as NSArray!

for application in applications {
   if  application.isKindOfClass(Dictionary) {
        //Im getting this error in above if statmet "Type Dictionary<Type, Value> does not confirm to protocol 'AnyObject'"          
   }
}
```

How to use isKindOfClass for dictionary? Whether the if check is not required or the way i'm doing is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `isKindOfClass` requires an `AnyClass` type – that is, a type that is a class.  Dictionaries aren’t classes, they’re structs, and thus can’t be held by an `AnyObject`.

If you switch your code to `application.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)` it should work (work in the sense that it will compile, and check if the type is an `NSDictionary`).

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished multiple ways.  If you know the key and value types you can check using `is` like this:

```
for application in applications {
    if application is Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

You can also use conditional assignment:

```
for application in applications {
    if let applicationDictionary = application as [String: AnyObject] {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to make sure it is an instance of `NSDictionary` you can use `application.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)`.